# Prove that $\exists 2$ paths between any two points in the graph

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a connected graph with the degree of all vertices being even. I want to prove that for any two vertices, $u$, $v$, there exist two paths between them with no common edges.

My attempt: if only one path exists between $u$ and $v$, then the edges along this path are bridges. If two paths exist between $u$ and $v$, but one of the edges of these two paths is the same, then this edge will be a bridge. Thus, proving that $G$ is bridgeless is sufficient. Assume that a bridge, $b$, does exist in $G$. Then we can write:
$$G-b=\tilde{G}_1\cup\tilde{G}_2$$
with $u\in\tilde{G}_1$ and $v\in\tilde{G}_2$. We know that the degree of all vertices in $\tilde{G}_1$ were even, but by removing the edge between $u$ and $v$, the degree of $u$ is now odd. Therefore, the sum of the degrees of all vertices in $\tilde{G}_1$ is odd, which is against the first theorem of graph theory. This shows by contradiction that $G$ is bridgeless and therefore (I believe) proves the statement in the top of the post.

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Yes, your proof is valid. But you should edit your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391140/property-of-a-connected-graph-with-textdegall-nodes-texteven/) instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Thank you, @MikeEarnest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid, but the existence of a bridge is not proved. Why does the fact that any two $st$-path intersects imply that there is a bridge? If you know Menger's theorem or max-flow min-cut, then that would complete your proof. Otherwise, there is still some work to do...

Comment: I get your point. If we assume that _all_ paths between $u$ and $v$ share a common edge, then this edge must be a bridge. But two paths could have a common edge which is not a bridge if there exist more than two paths. So why is my proof valid considering that mistake?

Comment: It is just a hole in your proof. Once you fill that hole, it will be correct. And as I said, if you know Menger's theorem or max-flow min-cut, the hole is easily filled.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia site of Menger's theorem, a graph is $k$-edge-connected if and only if every pair of vertices has $k$ edge-disjoint paths in between. Since I have shown that removing one edge is not sufficient to separate the graph into $\tilde{G}_1$ and $\tilde{G}_2$, I have shown that there must exist a minimum of two edge-disjoint paths between every two vertices. That completes the proof, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed. But now, you need a proof of Menger's theorem :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)